# How do I Pythonically print a list with formatting?

Tags: list, string-formatting, python

I have a list:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and I want to print

```
1 B 2 J 3 C 4 A 5 J 6 X
```

from that list.

How do I do that?

Do I have to make another list and `zip` them up, or is there some way I can have the letters in my format specifier?

Comment: Where does theses letters come from?

Comment: They are constant. They are going to be SI unit prefixes, like yotta, zeta, kilo, mega, ...

Comment: Ok, it was easy to guess. (irony)

Comment: You'll also have *hella* for ten to the twenty-seventh, right?

Comment: It's bronto for 10 to the twenty-seventh.

Comment: What the hell? When was that finalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to do this is have a dictionary of numbers to prefixes:

```
prefixes = {1: 'B', 2: 'J', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'J', 6: 'X'}
```

Then you can do:

```
print ' 'join('%s %s' % (num, prefix) for num, prefix in prefixes.itervalues())
```

If you also have a list of letters:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
ltrs = ['B', 'J', 'C', 'A', 'J', 'X']

print ' '.join('%s %s' % (num, ltr) for num, ltr in zip(nums, ltrs)
```

Comment: `ltrs` doesn't have to be a list, it can just be a `str`ing.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it either way:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

from itertools import chain

# new method
print "{} B {} J {} C {} A {} J {} X".format(*L)
# old method
print "%s B %s J %s C %s A %s J %s X" % tuple(L)
# without string formatting
print ' '.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(map(str, L), 'BJCAJX')))
```

See the docs on [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) and [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).